# How to extract values of different sizes from an array of uint8_t?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, tcp

I am trying to receive a message of a TCP socket and store it in an `uint8_t` array.
The buffer I am to receive is to be 8 bytes long and contains 4 unique values. 
Byte 1: value 1 which is a uint8_t, Byte 2-3: value 2 which is a uint16_t, Byte 4: value 3 which is a uint8_t, Byte 5-8: value 4 which is an unsigned long.
Endiannessis big endian order.

```
int numBytes = 0;
uint8_t buff [8];
if ((numBytes = recv(sockfd, buff, 8, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}

uint8_t *pt = buff;
printf("buff[0] = %u\n", *pt);
++pt;
printf("buff[1] = %u\n", *(uint16_t*)pt);
```

But the second `printf` prints out an unexpected value. Have I done something incorrectly to extract the two bytes or is something wrong with my print function?

Comment: Impossible to answer until you explain what "Byte 2-3: value 2" means, i.e., how those bytes should be translated into a value. Same for value 4.

Comment: We don't know the endianness of the multi-byte values, but I don't see any purpose in complicating the issue by using a pointer, instead of indexing `buff` directly as an array, and extracting the values element by element.

Comment: @PeteBecker that seems clear to me: value 2 mean second value.

Comment: @WeatherVane - huh? Of course value2 means second value. Did you **read** my comment before you replied to it?

Comment: @PeteBecker I expect my first comment was pretty much the same as your first comment.

Comment: The recent question edit has still not answered the endianness issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have added the expected types. I also didn't expect this to be the best way I am just trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I have specified the endianness.

Comment: @WeatherVane I used your suggestion on using indexing instead of what i was trying to do. I don't know why I didn't realize that before. If you post it as an answer I will select it as best answer.

Comment: @user3577756 I already did.

Comment: The endianness is only important if the sending machine may have a different endianness to the receiving machine. Is that the case?

Comment: Important note about TCP: It is stream, not message, based. Never assume that you got the whole message just because `recv` didn't return an error. `recv` returns what it has available *up to* the number of bytes you asked for. In this case `recv` could return 0 (socket politely closed), 1, or 2. If you want N bytes, you may have to loop `recv` until you receive N bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this (big-endian)

```
uint8_t buff [8];
// ... 
uint8_t       val1 = buff[0];
unit16_t      val2 = buff[1] * 256 + buff[2];
unit8_t       val3 = buff[3];
unsigned long val4 = buff[4] * 16777216 + buff[5] * 65536 + buff[6] * 256 + buff[7];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 issues to take care of once your data has arrived in the buffer.

The first is obeying *aliasing rules* which is achieved by only casting non-char type pointers to `char*` because `char` can alias *anything*. You should *never* cast `char*` to non-char type pointers.

The second is obeying network byte ordering protocol whereby integers transmitted over a network are converted to network order before transfer and converted from network order after receipt. For this we generally use `htons`, `htonl`, `ntohs` and `ntohl`.

Something like this:

```
// declare receive buffer to be char, not uint8_t
char buff[8]; 

// receive chars in buff here ...

// now transfer and convert data
uint8_t a;
uint16_t b;
uint8_t c;
uint32_t d;

a = static_cast<uint8_t>(buff[0]);

// always cast the receiving type* to char*
// never cast char* to receiving type*
std::copy(buff + 1, buff + 3, (char*)&b)

// convert from network byte order to host order
b = ntohs(b); // short version (uint16_t)

c = static_cast<uint8_t>(buff[3]);

std::copy(buff + 4, buff + 8, (char*)&d)

d = ntohl(d); // long version (uint32_t)
```