# c++ convert four unsined chars to one unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting

In my c++ program I have a  structure containing four `unsigned char` members

```
struct msg
{
    unsigned char zero; unsigned char one; unsigned char two; unsigned char three;
}
```

and created an array of struct

```
msg myMsg[4] = {{0x11,0x22,0xAA,0xCC},{...},{...},{...}};
```

now in a function I want to return an index of this array as an `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int procMsg(int n){
  return myMsg[n]; // of course this is worng
}
```

a value like: `0xCCAA2211`

Comment: [typically type pun via memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801)

Comment: Is there a reason to not do `uint32_t ival = myMsg[n].zero | (myMsg[n].one << 8) | (myMsg[n].two << 16) | (myMsg[n].three << 24)` ?

Comment: @ChrisD thanks a lot, actually this is the answer, well I am new to c/c++ and did not know even what to search for

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40332770/509868

Comment: Cool, I asked the question in case there was some crucial performance reason to not use all the shifts and ors. If there was then @ShafikYaghmour's answer is worth reading, but note you'd need to make sure the `struct msg` was packed into 4 bytes without any padding (although it almost always would be).

Comment: @ChrisD thanks for the hint, actually I am just making dummy data from what a device will send, which is promised to be correct :)

Comment: Why doesn't your `procMsg()` simply return a `msg`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because the signature is following an API calls from legacy system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shifting:

```
uint32_t little_endian;
uint32_t big_endian;
//...
big_endian = myMsg[0].zero << 24
           | myMsg[0].one  << 16
           | myMsg[0].two  <<  8
           | myMsg[0].three;
little_endian = myMsg[0].three << 24
                myMsg[0].two   << 16
                myMsg[0].one   <<  8
                myMsg[0].zero;
```

As you can see, with multi-byte integers, there are two general orderings:  Big Endian and Little Endian.  Big Endian has the Most Significant Byte (MSB) first.  The Little Endian has Least Significant Byte (LSB) first.

In general the above method is more efficient than using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

consider this:

a message like this: `{0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}` can be parsed as

00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001(bin) = 16.843.009(dec)

so you just need to take every char and shift them according to its position 
i.e.

> char0 not shifted at all,
>
> char1 shifted 8 positions to the left (or multiply by 2^8)
>
> char2 shifted 16 positions to the left (or multiply by 2^(8*2))
>
> char3 shifted 24 positions to the left (or multiply by 2^(8*3))

```
unsigned int procMsg(Message &x)
{
    return (x.three << 24) |
           (x.two << 16) |
           (x.one << 8) |
           x.zero;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                         //0     1     2     3
    Message myMsg[4] = {{0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01},  //00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 = 16.843.009
                        {0xFF, 0x00, 0xAA, 0xCC},  //00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 = 3.433.693.439
                        {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},  //00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 = 1
                        {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}   //00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 = 0
                       };

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        Message x = myMsg[i];
        std::cout << "res: " << procMsg(myMsg[i]) << std::endl;
    }

    return  0;

}
```